# Faster extraction data from site with python and openpyxl

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, openpyxl

I have a website where I consult information. It has three variables and when you click the search button, it finds information associated with those variables, which is reflected in a html table. I built a robot, since checking the information manually is very slow. The robot takes the data of the three variables for each row within an Excel file, enters them in the inputs and then clicks the search button. Then it takes each of the rows from the generated table and appends them to a txt file. Then it goes to the next line of the Excel file and repeats the process as many rows as the Excel file has. The problem I have is that I would like the writing process to be much faster, this because I have to query at least 100000 rows and only with 1000 rows it takes about an hour. Is there any way that I could do these queries more quickly? I know that with an API this query would be possible in a faster way but that option is not possible.
Here is my code. Thanks and Greetings!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_path= ".\\chromedriver.exe"
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless") 
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  
options.add_argument('start-maximized') 
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'.\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://WEBSITE")
file = "CONSULTA.xlsx"
    
def login(driver):
    driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('usernameField').value = 'MAIL@MAIL.cl' ; document.getElementById('passwordField').value = 'PASS' ") 
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#loginForm > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=submit]").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a").click()
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#check1").click()
    
    
def sendvalues(driver):
   
    wb = load_workbook(filename=file,read_only= True)
    ws = wb['CONSULTA']
    buscar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#wrapper > form > div:nth-child(5) > input:nth-child(1)")
    info1value=  ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value
    info2value= ws.cell(row=x, column=2).value
    nombrevalue= ws.cell(row=x, column=3).value
    scriptinfo1 = 'document.getElementById("info1").value='+"'"+str(info1value)+"'"+';'+'document.querySelector("#wrapper > form > table.tabla_datos > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=text]").value='+"'"+str(info2value)+"'"+";"+'document.querySelector("#wrapper > form > table.tabla_datos > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=text]").value ='+"'"+nombrevalue+"'"
    driver.execute_script(scriptinfo1)  
    buscar.click()
    table(driver)
    wb.close()
    
def table(driver):
    info1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#info1")))
    info2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#wrapper > form > table.tabla_datos > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=text]")
    nombre = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#wrapper > form > table.tabla_datos > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > input[type=text]")
    wb1 = load_workbook(filename= file, read_only=True)
    ws = wb1['CONSULTA']
    info1value=  ws.cell(row=x, column=1).value
    info2value=  ws.cell(row=x, column=2).value
    text_file = open("Output.txt", "a")
    try:
        table_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.1).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#grilla_resultados")))
        for table_element in table_elements:
            for row in table_element.find_elements_by_css_selector("#grilla_resultados > tbody > tr"):
                
                text_file.write(str(info1value)+","+str(info2value)+","+str(row.text)+'\n')
                info1.clear()
                info2.clear()
                nombre.clear()

    except TimeoutException:
                text_file.write(str(info1value)+","+str(info2value)+","+str("Sin Resultados")+'\n')
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#nav > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a").click()
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#check1").click() 
        
    text_file.close()     

            
now = datetime.now()
dt_string = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("Iniciado a: "+dt_string)   
login(driver)

for x in range(1,100000):
   sendvalues(driver)
   
now2 = datetime.now()
print("Extracción completa...")
dt_string2 = now2.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("Ejecución completa a: "+dt_string2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are opening, loading in memory and closing your Excel file twice for each iteration; and opening and closing your txt once for each iteration.

Just do these tasks once, outside the loop:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename=file,read_only= True)
ws = wb['CONSULTA']
with open("Output.txt", "a") as text_file:
    for x in range(1,100000):
        sendvalues(driver)
wb.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @gimix. With this approach I save 1 second, which is very useful. Is there any other method that can help me reduce the execution time?